# wp-login behind nginx reverse-proxy inaccessible — bad redirect?

Tags: admin, login, installation, nginx, proxy

i’ve setup WordPress on a local nginx backend instance. the backend url is

```
https://wp.example.com:12345/
```

it’s served through a frontend, nginx reverse proxy, exposed at a subdir. the frontend url is

```
https://example.com/cms
```

wp-config.php includes

```
define('WP_HOME',   'https://example.com/cms');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://example.com/cms');
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = str_replace("/wp-admin/", "/cms/wp-admin/",  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = str_replace("/wp-login/", "/cms/wp-login/",  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

if i nav to

```
https://example.com/cms
```

I see the usual/expected

```
”
Hello world!
Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start writing!
“
```

But if I nav to LOGIN

```
https://example.com/cms/login
```

I’m redirected to

```
https://wp.example.com/login/
```

which is the backend, without the port (12345), and of course fails

```
“Unable to connect”
```

Proxy to the frontpage obviously works.

Proxy to the login page fails, with that^ incorrect redirect.

There’s a config or rewrite missing.

What/where needs to change to fix that login redirect?

Comment: Any luck with solving this issue? @huna